# How to toggle active class with navbar links on click javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to toggle the "li-active" class to each of my nav-bar link li when clicked. At the moment, after the first click, the current li-active class gets removed and carries the class to the newly clicked li. Great. Yet, when clicked on a different li the previous li doesn't remove the class, but the new li gets the class.
I may be overlooking a step.. thank you in advance!

```
 <li data-id="0" id="mercury" class="navbar__links--li">
              <div class="inner-div">
                <div class="mercury-oval"></div>
                MERCURY
              </div>
              <svg
                class="svg"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="6"
                height="8"
              >
                <path fill="none" stroke="#FFF" opacity=".4" d="M1 0l4 4-4 4" />
              </svg>
            </li>
            <li data-id="1" id="venus" class="navbar__links--li">
              <div class="inner-div">
                <div class="venus-oval"></div>
                VENUS
              </div>
              <svg
                class="svg"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="6"
                height="8"
              >
                <path fill="none" stroke="#FFF" opacity=".4" d="M1 0l4 4-4 4" />
              </svg>
            </li>
            <li data-id="2" id="earth" class="navbar__links--li li-active">
              <div class="inner-div">
                <div class="earth-oval"></div>
                EARTH
              </div>
              <svg
                class="svg"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="6"
                height="8"
              >
                <path fill="none" stroke="#FFF" opacity=".4" d="M1 0l4 4-4 4" />
              </svg>
            </li>
            <li data-id="3" id="mars" class="navbar__links--li">
              <div class="inner-div">
                <div class="mars-oval"></div>
                MARS
              </div>
              <svg
                class="svg"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="6"
                height="8"
              >
                <path fill="none" stroke="#FFF" opacity=".4" d="M1 0l4 4-4 4" />
              </svg>
            </li>
            <li data-id="4" id="jupiter" class="navbar__links--li">
              <div class="inner-div">
                <div class="jupiter-oval"></div>
                JUPITER
              </div>
              <svg
                class="svg"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="6"
                height="8"
              >
                <path fill="none" stroke="#FFF" opacity=".4" d="M1 0l4 4-4 4" />
              </svg>
            </li>
            <li data-id="5" id="saturn" class="navbar__links--li">
              <div class="inner-div">
                <div class="saturn-oval"></div>
                SATURN
              </div>
              <svg
                class="svg"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="6"
                height="8"
              >
                <path fill="none" stroke="#FFF" opacity=".4" d="M1 0l4 4-4 4" />
              </svg>
            </li>
            <li data-id="6" id="uranus" class="navbar__links--li">
              <div class="inner-div">
                <div class="uranus-oval"></div>
                URANUS
              </div>
              <svg
                class="svg"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="6"
                height="8"
              >
                <path fill="none" stroke="#FFF" opacity=".4" d="M1 0l4 4-4 4" />
              </svg>
            </li>
            <li data-id="7" id="neptune" class="navbar__links--li">
              <div class="inner-div">
                <div class="neptune-oval"></div>
                NEPTUNE
              </div>
              <svg
                class="svg"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="6"
                height="8"
              >
                <path fill="none" stroke="#FFF" opacity=".4" d="M1 0l4 4-4 4" />
              </svg>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

```
.li-active {
  @include desktop {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

```
menuBtn.forEach((li) => {
  li.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    menuBtn.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("li-active"));
    e.target.classList.add("li-active");
  });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's because you're adding the class to the clicked target, which could be any inner element.

Replace it with the clicked element itself (`li.classlist.add`):

```
let menuBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar__links--li')

    menuBtn.forEach((li) => {
        li.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            menuBtn.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("li-active"));
            li.classList.add("li-active");
        });
    });
```